# Pyspark UDF column to numpy array conversion failing with PickleException

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a UDF defined as below:

```
import numpy as np

@udf("array<array<float>>") 
def myfunc(arr, n):
    return np.pad(arr, [(n, 0), (0, 0)], "constant", constant_values=0.0).tolist()
```

And code that invokes it as follows:

```
result = temp_result.withColumn(my_col, myfunc(my_col, lit(5)))
```

The schema/type for `my_col` and its dataframe is:

```
root

 |-- my_col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- word_count: integer (nullable = false)
```

As you might imagine, when I run the code, I get an error saying:

```
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:773)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:213)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:123)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.$anonfun$evaluate$6(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:83)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

However, I'm not sure how to fix it. I guess I'll need to convert the column to `numpy` array, but not sure how to do it with the UDF.

Any hepl will be greatly appreciated.